# Dividing some columns by one column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 3 data columns, and a 4<sup>th</sup> column. The three columns should each be divided by the 4<sup>th</sup> column. I want to get a dataframe with the three columns divided as described, and the 4<sup>th</sup> column to remain there unchanged.

I used `div()` command but I only get the three divided columns without the 4<sup>th</sup> column:

```
import panda as pd

df

alpha    beta    gama   theta
20.77   20.87   19.87    4.5
19.87   19.89   19.56   5.5
19.56   19.96   20.1    7.5
20.1    20.4    20.53   8

df = df[["alpha", "beta", "gama"]].div(df.theta, axis=0)
```

**I want to get** this data frame:

```
df
alpha      beta    gama   theta
4.615     4.63    4.415    4.5
3.612     3.616   3.556    5.5
2.608     2.661   2.68     7.5
2.5125    2.55    2.566    8
```

But **I'm currently getting** this:

```
df
alpha      beta    gama   
4.615     4.63    4.415    
3.612     3.616   3.556  
2.608     2.661   2.68   
2.5125    2.55    2.566
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_df = df.copy()
new_df[["alpha","beta","gama"]] = new_df.div(df.theta, axis=0)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign only filtered rows by list and also divide only filtered columns:

```
cols = ["alpha", "beta", "gama"]
df[cols] = df[cols].div(df.theta, axis=0)
print (df)
      alpha      beta      gama  theta
0  4.615556  4.637778  4.415556    4.5
1  3.612727  3.616364  3.556364    5.5
2  2.608000  2.661333  2.680000    7.5
3  2.512500  2.550000  2.566250    8.0
```

Another idea is select first 3 columns by position in [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[:, :3] = df.iloc[:, :3].div(df.theta, axis=0)
print (df)
      alpha      beta      gama  theta
0  4.615556  4.637778  4.415556    4.5
1  3.612727  3.616364  3.556364    5.5
2  2.608000  2.661333  2.680000    7.5
3  2.512500  2.550000  2.566250    8.0
```